# Are there data on physical album sales by city/state/region for 2000-2010?

Tags: data-request, music

I'm looking for data on physical sales of popular music albums in the United States by geographic region, e.g. city, state, or region? As fine-grained as possible? Ideally, I'm looking for data for the years 2000 to 2010, or even earlier.